# how to do Django query that is ordered by latlng string

Tags: python, django, django-models

**Current Situation**

I Am fetching data that contains Strings that represent the Latlng of some locations .. like `30.78829892811801,31.2769004988329` `30.78848118485095,31.27649189363398` `30.78869531217787,31.27615745128788` etc.

**What I have tried**

now I am doing Django query like `ModelName.objects.all().order_by('latlng')` but it is not ordering it as the field is simply a `Charfield` .. also converting it to `double` is not working as it contains 2 different double separated by the comma.

**What I need to do**

Is there a way to convert this string to `LatLng` that is orderable by location or something like this?

Comment: another approach is before saving the latlng, split the string by ',' to get string number of the lat and long. Convert the string to float and save each of it to new float columns instead of just 1 CharField column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Postgres? If so, you can use the `ArrayField` to split out your string into an array that might make it more easily-sortable in the ORM.

```py
from django.db.models import F, Value, DecimalField
from django.db.models.expressions import Func
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField

latlng_arr_func = Func(
    F('latlng'),
    Value(","),
    function='regexp_split_to_array', output=ArrayField(DecimalField())
)

ModelName.objects.annotate(latlng_arr=latlng_arr_func).order_by('-latlng_arr')
```

Then calling `object.latlng_arr` should yield a list of your values `[30.78829892811801,31.2769004988329]`.

If this doesn't get you the result you want then I would suggest either splitting the data into two decimal fields on your model (you could still keep the string version) or order the data using Python.